# Github authentication issue while installing yii php framework

Tags: php, github, yii

I tried to install `yii` php framework. I used the following commands to install that framework:
1. `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"`
2. `composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.2`
This was the output:

```
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.2)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

Created project in advanced
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading bower.json of bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (3.1.50)
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/contents/bower.json?ref=f44d5deec804c72fe85da31819b18bdcdad26f65, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /home/ajay/.composer/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: akulkarni9
Password: 
Token successfully created

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/authorizations, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /home/ajay/.composer/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: akulkarni9
Password: 
An existing OAuth token for Composer is present and will be reused

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/authorizations, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /home/ajay/.composer/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username: akulkarni9
Password: 
An existing OAuth token for Composer is present and will be reused

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/authorizations, enter your GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /home/ajay/.composer/auth.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
Username:
```

I don't understand why `github` keeps asking me again and again for my github `username` and `password`. I thought that `OAuth token` will be stored in `/home/<username>/.composer/auth.json` file. Why isn't it being reused?

Comment: 1. Make sure that file exists and contains something that looks reasonable. 2. Try updating Composer (`composer self-update`) and see if that helps.

Comment: I used `sudo /usr/local/bin/composer self-update` and tried to install `yii` framework again. I'll update you with results :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance this looks like a bug with Composer. Luckily, the team behind Composer is continually improving it and releasing new versions.

Updating Composer with [`composer self-update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update) is likely to fix the problem.

In this case the OP reported in comments above that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in to your GitHub account. Then create new token at https://github.com/settings/tokens/new with required scope. The generated token can be provided as OAuth token while installing the Yii2.